# How Do I Broadcast Json To Users via Node JS server?

Tags: node.js

**Goal**: After user saves data to my mysql DB, a JSON teaser of the newly saved content is broadcasted to all users.

What are some quick and dirty solutions to achieve this? I am working with php/mysql. Got a taste of Socket.io, and a node.js server listening on the side....

Any good links would be greatly appreciated.

Background--------
After many years of working with php, I have decided to jump onto the NodeJS Bandwagon- and have no clue to do anything other than the vanilla "Hello World".... This is my starting point. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to broadcast to all users including yourself, then you should use:

```
io.sockets.emit('global', {data: 'this will be received by everyone'});
```

If you would like to broadcast to all users without yourself being notified, then you should use:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('Hello everyone!');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! I'm a big fan of one-liners... I will test this with my setup and provide feedback soon.

Answer (score 1):

Can you define what you mean by "broadcast" in this context?

Do you want to display an alert on a web page?

If so, do you wish to alert only those users who are currently viewing pages on your site or those who come to your site during a period of time?  If the later, do you care if the alert appears to a single user more than once?

Socket.IO is one way to transmit/receive messages to/from a remote browser, but without a client-side handler that has some way of displaying your message to the user, it's kind of moot.

I've found now.js to be a far better abstraction of browser<-->server communications as shown in this possible solution that will display an alert on pages currently viewed by your users:

Step 1: Install now.js (remove the -g if you don't want now installed globally):

> `npm install -g now`

Step 2: Create a HTTP server and cause it to listen on a port 80

```js
var PORT=80,
    http=require('http'),
    nowjs=require('now'),
    app=http.createServer(requestHandler).listen(PORT), // create your server
    everyone=nowjs.initialize(app); // initialize now on your listening server

function alertUsers(msg){ // sends msg to showAlert() callback on clients
    everyone.now.showAlert(msg); 
}

function requestHandler(req,res) {
    ...
    ...
    /* 
     * Ok, something has happened you want to inform your currently
     * connected users of...
     * 
     * if the thing can happen as a result of a request, do it here
     */
    var msg="Whoohoo! Something's happened!";
    alertUsers(msg);
    ...
    ...
}

// or if it happens somewhere else, just call alertUsers() there.
```

Step 3: And then in the browser-side HTML:

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                .alert  { background-color:red; color:white; font:24pt bold sans-serif; }
                .hidden { display:hidden; visibility:none; }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="alert" class="alert hidden">
            <div class="main-content">
                <!-- main page content -->
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="...load jQuery here..."></script>
            <script src="/nowjs/now.js"></script> <!-- *SEE NOTE BELOW -->
            <script type="text/javascript>
                $(document).ready(function(){ 
                    // after the document has finished loading
                    now.showAlert=function(msg){ // define your callback function
                        $('#alert').removeClass('hidden').text(msg);
                    };
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

* Note that the `<script src="/nowjs/now.js"></script>` request is magic in that the referenced file doesn't really exist server-side at that location. By running nowjs.initialize() on your http server instance, you're setting things up so that nowjs will intercept the request for `/nowjs/now.js` and serve it back to the client without invoking your requestHandler().

Also, this solution does not display your alert to anyone who connects after the alert is sent from the server. If you want to do that, you'll need to do something different.

Comment: Very interesting! Never heard of this framework before. I'm still up in the air as to what method I should do to "broadcast" (for lack of a better word) events to users.  And "broadcast"? I'm using this term in a general sense...not keeping in mind authentication or any of that jazz. Just real time sharing of events. Anyway..IF this NOW.JS framework is specifically designed to do just that, then I may have a fair amount of honework to do!